# Why do some PRS guitars have bird inlays?

Tags: electric-guitar

What is the story behind the bird inlays of the PRS guitars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all down to Paul's mother, who was an avid ornithologist - a bird-watcher. She encouraged an interest in birds for Paul, and when he made his first (hand-made) guitar - for Peter Frampton, in April '76, as a 20 yr old, he decided to go avant-garde, and make the markings of the fretboard resemble the silhouettes of certain birds. (Peter was guitarist with The Herd and Humble Pie.) The largest being a Cooper's hawk (resident in US) for the 12th fret, that being possibly the most important landmark on the fretboard (citation needed..!).

Now, someone who orders a bespoke PRS guitar can specify which profiles go where, an I'm pretty sure ivory from old piano keys isn't used any more.

Comment: The PRS company also bought the Frampton guitar back

Answer (score 3):

Paul Reed Smith said about why he chose the bird inlays the following...

> “My mother was a bird watcher,” said Paul Reed Smith.
>
> When Paul was a young boy, his mother would take him and his siblings
> birdwatching, and occasionally to the Smithsonian in Washington, D.C.
> Paul recalled, “At the time, the Smithsonian allowed you to take out a
> record like a book from a library, we would get records of bird songs
> and listen to them. At night, we would listen to the birds in our
> rooms with the windows open, these were nightbird songs,
> whip-poor-wills.”
>
> “My mom really knew and loved birds and exposed us to them,” he
> mentioned. “One time there were a few starlings in our backyard and my
> mom went off, she said, ’This is going to be a problem, those are
> scouts.’ We said, 'What do you mean?' She said, 'They're searching for
> a place for the entire huge flock.' In the next few days, sure enough,
> thousands of starlings were in our backyard terrorizing every other
> bird in the yard and eating everything. My mother called it, she knew
> what was going to happen. She called them flying rats. It was loud and
> raucus and we watched them fight with the cardinals and the robins.”

> In April of 1976, 9 years before the official foundation of PRS
> Guitars, Paul was 20 years old and was building a guitar for rock
> musician Peter Frampton. “When it came time to put inlays on the
> fretboard,” Paul said, “I didn’t even have to think about it, I just
> went down to the store, bought a bird guide, and started designing
> inlays.”

Starting from the nut the birds are:

- Peregrine falcon
- Marsh Hawk
- Ruby Throated Hummingbird
- Common Tern
- Coopers Hawk
- Kite
- Sparrow Landing
- Storm Petrel
- Hawk Landing
- Screech Owl On A Branch (24-fret models only)

There has also been a number of variations on the bird theme.

Solid Birds

[image: Solid Birds]

J-Birds

[image: J-birds]

J-Birds with centers

[image: Jbirds with centers]

Brushstroke Birds

[image: Brushstroke Birds]

513 Birds

[image: 513 birds]

20th-anniversary birds

[image: 20th-anniversary birds]

[SOURCE](https://prsguitars.com/blog/post/the_story_of_the_prs_bird_inlays)